# Program being stuck in a for loop but doesn't return anything Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

The for loop inside of my program (**python using pygame**) doesn't print or return anything (meaning it stops looping) but the outside return and print lines also aren't run.

Here's the function I'm referring to:

```
def square_under_attack(posx, posy):
    print("SQUARE UNDER ATTACK FUNCTION CALLED")
    global white_to_move
    white_to_move = not white_to_move
    enemy_moves = generate_possible_moves()
    white_to_move = not white_to_move
    x=0
    for opponent_move in enemy_moves:
        print(x)
        if opponent_move[3] == posx and opponent_move[4] == posy:  # if the opponent can move to the square being tested
            print("returned true")
            return True
        x+=1
    print("returned false")
    return False
```

This function gets stuck when being called to by this function (Included incase the previous function has something to do with the running of this function - I'm quite stuck on this issue so any extra info to help you all I thought would be useful.)

```
def check_check():
    global white_to_move
    global white_king
    global black_king
    if white_to_move is True:
        return square_under_attack(white_king[0], white_king[1])
    else:
        return square_under_attack(black_king[0], black_king[1])
```

For those wondering, here is what the `generate_possible_moves()` function returns in this scenario:

```
[(6, 0, 5, 0), (6, 0, 4, 0), (6, 1, 5, 1), (6, 1, 4, 1), (6, 2, 5, 2), (6, 2, 4, 2), (6, 3, 5, 3), (6, 3, 4, 3), (6, 4, 5, 4), (6, 4, 4, 4), (6, 5, 5, 5), (6, 5, 4, 5), (6, 6, 5, 6), (6, 6, 4, 6), (6, 7, 5, 7), (6, 7, 4, 7), (7, 1, 5, 2), (7, 1, 5, 0), (7, 6, 5, 7), (7, 6, 5, 5)]
```

Comment: What returns "generate_possible_moves" function? If it isn't too long, add its code. Generally, a debugger can help to narrow down the problem (or at least some more "print"s in the code).

Comment: Generate_possible_ moves returns a list of 20 tuples, I’ll send the code in 2 seconds, lemme just copy and paste it

Comment: [(6, 0, 5, 0), (6, 0, 4, 0), (6, 1, 5, 1), (6, 1, 4, 1), (6, 2, 5, 2), (6, 2, 4, 2), (6, 3, 5, 3), (6, 3, 4, 3), (6, 4, 5, 4), (6, 4, 4, 4), (6, 5, 5, 5), (6, 5, 4, 5), (6, 6, 5, 6), (6, 6, 4, 6), (6, 7, 5, 7), (6, 7, 4, 7), (7, 1, 5, 2), (7, 1, 5, 0), (7, 6, 5, 7), (7, 6, 5, 5)] is the return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the code was trying to index a 4 digit tuple with a 5:

```
if opponent_move[3] == posx and opponent_move[4] == posy:
```

The `opponent_move` was referring to a list similar to this:

```
if opponent_move[3] == posx and opponent_move[4] == posy:
```

So it was index erroring out and triggering error fallbacks in other sections of the program.